# what is the best way to pull specific rows our of 2 dim array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops

I am looking to use the most efficient way possible to pull rows from my data (currently 25 columns and 19864 rows, but this will get larger in the future).

So I have certain columns that I can use to flag certain running conditions.  So like if column 25 is > 0 I would like to pull that whole row of data into another array and keep building on that array from the original.

I have tried this:

```
a = 22
b = 24

data2 = []
inc = 0
for i in data[:,a]:
    if data[i,b] > 0:
        data2[inc,0] = data[i,a]
        data2[inc,1] = data[i,b]
    inc += 1
print (inc)
```

and am getting an error in the if statement line 
`if data[i,b] > 0:`, the error is **IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices**

Comment: `Look at `i` before try to use it as an index

Comment: @hpaulj is right. When you loop over data, as in `for i in data[:,a]`, `i` is not an index but the value of your array. A better loop for you would be `for i, val in enumerate(data[:,a])`. Now in your loop `i` is an index and `val` is the value at that index in your array.

Comment: Also worth considering what you mean by "column 25 is > 0". You would be able to evaluate whether every value in column 25 is greater than 0, or if the sum of column 25 is greater than 0 for example, but the condition you described doesn't make much sense in terms of numpy arrays. Just a thought.

Comment: @Paddy Harrison sorry maybe I am misunderstanding you.  My point of wanting to check if the values in col 25 > 0 is to pull that row of data into another array along with all the other rows where col 25 >0.  Then as my code progresses I will take the second array and analyze that data further.

Comment: What is `data[i,b]` supposed to do, when `i` is a column of `data`?  `i` isn't an index.

Comment: Show `data` if you want more help.  And sow `i`